# Show that $5\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I showed this: $5\mathbb{Z}+5\mathbb{Z}=5\mathbb{Z}$.

i.e., $5\mathbb{Z}+5\mathbb{Z}=5(\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z})$. So, since we know $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$, $5\mathbb{Z}+5\mathbb{Z}=5(\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z})=5\mathbb{Z}$.

So, how can I prove $5\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(3,5)=1$.

Comment: The notation above is slightly messy, but it sounds like you are asking to show that every integer can be written as a sum of two integers, one of which a multiple of five, and one of which a multiple of three.  As Fimpellizieri points out, $\gcd(5,3)=1$.  As a more explicit hint, $1=-1\cdot 5 + 2\cdot 3$.

Comment: This is not (elementary-set-theory).  This is elementary number theory.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri That is not a hint, that is the answer!

Comment: @Jasper You also need to know the corollary of [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). Or notice that $3(2)+5(-1)=1$. Here [the extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) can help to find the $(2), (-1)$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Can you see my answer?

Comment: @Jasper Can you see my answer?

Comment: @Kahler: Generalize this!! Show that this is true whenever $(m,n) = 1$.

Comment: @Kahler I can see your proof. See my comment there :P

Comment: I was just commenting it when you came up with it. I think you were on the good track and that your proof contained the good ideas. Yet you needed to be clear about what $z$ meant. I'll write an answer inspired by your method.

Comment: @Jasper Did you see my new answer?

Comment: 5(-1)+ 3(2)= 1. Thus 5(-n)+3(2n)=n.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly $5\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}$. For the reverse inclusion, suppose $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\gcd(3,5)=1$, there exist integers $a,b$ such that $3a+5b=1$. Hence, $x=3(ax)+5(bx)\in3\mathbb{Z}+5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The fact that there exist such $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ follows from [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). Or simply by noticing $3(2)+5(-1)=1$. You can find the $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ using, e.g., [the extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: To explain my downvote (which was perhaps slightly unfair) I think "Hint: Bezout's lemma" would have been a better answer....

Answer (score 4):

$ \mathbb{Z} $ is a principal ideal domain, which means that the ideal $ J = 5\mathbb{Z} + 3\mathbb{Z} $ is principal, say $ J = (a) $. But $ 5 \in J $ and $ 3 \in J $, which means that $ a $ divides both $ 5 $ and $ 3 $, from which it follows that $ a = 1 $ and $ J = (1) = \mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: I would wager that the OP is not familiar with ideals.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, we have $5m+3n=1$ by the Bezout's lemma. Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $5(mk)+3(nk)=k$. So, we know $mk$ and $nk$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $k=5(mk)+3(nk)\in 5\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $5\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, is it enough and clear?

Comment: Perhaps you should delete your other answer?

Comment: Add $3\mathbb{Z} + 5\mathbb{Z} = \{ 3n + 5m ~:~ m,n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$, and that $\gcd(3,5)=1$ to it, and I think it's sufficiently clear in my opinion!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I just notice one thing. Strictly speaking you prove that $3\mathbb{Z} + 5\mathbb{Z} \supset \mathbb{Z}$, so it's still possible that for example $3\mathbb{Z} + 5\mathbb{Z} = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$. Adding a remark that $5\mathbb{Z} + 3\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ holds is for this reason of importance, yet you can also "whipe-it-off" as something that is trivial.

Comment: As written, it is still 'wrong'. Instead, try something like this: Because $\gcd(3,5)=1$, by Bezout's lemma there are $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $5m + 3n = 1$. Now, if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $5(mk)+3(nk)=k$, so $k \in 5\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}$; in other words, $\mathbb{Z} \subset 5\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}$. The other inclusion, that $5\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$,  is trivial and equality follows.

Comment: What I mean is I believe you got the idea, but your wording of the proof is all over the place.

Comment: It's not necessary to use Bézout's lemma. It's enough to notice that $5(-1)+3(2)=1$. Though of course Bézout's lemma gives the more general result: we have $a\mathbb Z+b\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

5(-1)+ 3(2)= 1. Thus 5(-n)+3(2n)=n.